# Get data of dynamic variable in twig

Tags: symfony, attributes, set, twig, entity

Hope someone tried this before or knows how to achieve what I'm trying to do.

I'm trying to get the data of the following variable.

```
{% if openingHours %}
   {% set name = "openingHours."~ myDate|date('l') ~ "Start" %}
   {% set openingHour = attribute(openingHours, name) %}
{% endif %}
```

The result should be e.g. `openingHour.MondayStart`. That's the variable I want the data from.

But it keeps throwing an error about the Entity.

[image: The Entity error]

I already checked if the data is accessible in twig via dump. The whole data of the entity can be accessed. If put `openingHour.MondayStart` in twig (hard coded) it gives me my desired data. But since it's a loop for all weekdays, I want data from all fields.

Comment: `{% set openingHour = attribute(openingHours, myDate|date('l') ~ "Start") %}`, rather.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`name` in your template should resolve to `MondayStart` but currently it's `openingHours.MondayStart` which you try to access on `openingHours` so what you're currently trying to access is `openingHours.openingHours.MondayStart`

your `set` tag should be

```
{% set name = myDate|date('l') ~ 'Start' %}
```

or you could do what [β.εηοιτ.βε](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74415959/get-data-of-dynamic-variable-in-twig/74416141#comment131369394_74415959) suggests, but I guess you want that name for something else as well.